# Cross origin iframe - showPicker usage

Tags: html, input, iframe, content-security-policy

I am having a trusted application embedded in my own application via an iframe. It works for most parts...but the custom date picker does not work -> as it throws a SecurityError as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/showPicker#securityerror

I have full control over both applications and can set any required tags / properties.

But what ever I tried, CSP with frame-ancestors / frame-src or Permissions-Policy does not work.

I saw in here https://developer.chrome.com/blog/show-picker

> We could add a permissions policy which allows cross-origin iframes to show browser pickers when their parent chain allows them to do so.

So am I correct that I have no way in Chromium based browsers to get the showPicker to work in a cross origin iframe usage as the permission policy is not yet there?

(Btw Firefox, we don't have an issue and the site works as expected.)